# Relationship between collection in Firebase

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, collections, nosql

I'm new to firebase and I'm trying to understand how to create a relationship between 2 collections. I have a book collection and a category collection and I can't connect this 2 between them. I'm thinking that this collections can connect by id, but the category in the book collection is like a string and not a reference to the category from the other collection.
[image]

I want to do that because somewhere in my angular application I need only the categories and not the books, that's why I created a new collection for categories.
Do you know how to help me?